# C# "Textchanged" event and infinite loop?

Tags: loops, events, textbox, infinite, textchanged

I'm currently creating an application that has three textboxes. Typing into one box will result in the other two having "converted" versions of the text displayed. All three boxes can be typed into and serve the same purpose (though provide different outputs for the conversion).

The "TextChanged" event is called whenever the text value of the box is changed, that is fairly self-explanatory. But will this event also trigger if I change the value through code.

Say if I changed the first box, it would create text in the second. Would the second box trigger the event as well? And would this result in an infinite loop?

Comment: I think this is an interesting situation, but one that I've seen implemented before.  I think you should write some code and find out!

Comment: I first tried writing out two strings (one for each conversion) and then apply said string to the box's text field. It refused to let me type when I tested it, constantly giving a blank text box. I assume that's because it was constantly applying a blank string each time I added something.

I changed it to call the conversion function (and hence apply new strings) when I pressed the enter key, rather than on textchanged. Works fine now but using the "enter" key creates a character that I don't know how to reference... but that's an entirely new problem.

Answer (score 1):

No, it wouldn't.  Text taken from the MSDN page on the event:

> The TextChanged event is raised when the content of the text box changes between posts to the server. The event is only raised if the text is changed by the user; the event is not raised if the text is changed programmatically.

[MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, or no.

this behavior differs from Winform and ASP.Net (each corresponding to System.Windows.Forms.TextBox and System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox), means that if you are to create ASP.Net application then the answer is no, but if you are working on Winform application then the answer is yes.
Please refer to the following different saying from the MSDN:

[System.Windows.Forms.Control.TextChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged)

> Remarks
>
> This event is raised if the Text property is changed by either a
>   programmatic modification or user interaction.
>
> For more information about handling events, see Handling and Raising
>   Events.

[System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox.TextChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged)

> The TextChanged event is raised when the content of the text box
>   changes between posts to the server. The event is only raised if the
>   text is changed by the user; the event is not raised if the text is
>   changed programmatically.